# Python: TypeError: det() argument after * must be an iterable, not Line

Tags: python

> I want to get the intersection between two lines my error.

I think in this line **d = (det(*self), det(*other))** it's the reason that gives me this error, I already calculated the slop and checked if its vertical lines also if the lines are parallel or not, if they equal, so it's just this error that doesn't let me finish my question if someone can recognize that error it will let me know that's errors better.

```
import math
import sys

class Point:
     '''Creates a point on a coordinate plane with values x and y.'''
     def __init__(self, x, y):
        '''Defines x and y variables'''
        if not isinstance(x, (float,int)):
            raise ValueError("the x must be an number", x)
        if not isinstance(y, (float,int)):
            raise ValueError("the x must be an number", y)
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y  

     def __str__(self):
        return "Point(%.2f,%.2f)"%(self.__x, self.__y)

     def setX(self,x):
         self.__x=x   
     def setY(self,y):
         self.__y=y 

     def getX(self):
        return self.__x
     def getY(self):
        return self.__y

class Line:
    ''' calculate the y=ax+b '''
    def __init__(self, point_1, point_2):
        self.__point_1=point_1
        self.__point_2=point_2

    def __str__(self):# print the object
        if self.slope()==None:
            return 'x={0}'.format(self.__point_1.getX())
        else:
            return 'y={0}x+{1}'.format(self.slope(),self.y_intersect())

    ''' set point 1 and 2 '''
    def setP1(self,point_1):
        self.__point_1=point_1
    def setP2(self,point_2):
        self.__point_2=point_2

    ''' get point 1 and 2'''
    def getP1(self):
        return self.__point_1
    def getP2(self):
        return self.__point_2

    def is_vertical(self):
        ''' check if the line is vertical '''
        if (self.__point_1.getX() == self.__point_2.getX()):
           return True
        else:
           return False

    def slope(self):
        ''' the slope of the line '''
        if self.is_vertical() == False:
            return( (self.__point_1.getY())-(self.__point_2.getY()) )   /  ( (self.__point_1.getX())-(self.__point_2.getX()) )    
        else:
            return None

    def y_intersect(self):
        ''' get the intersecton with Y '''
        b=-(self.slope()) * self.__point_1.getX() + self.__point_1.getY()
        # y=mx-mx1+y1 --> b=-mx1+y1 this is the y intersection
        return b

    def parallel(self,other):
        if self.slope()==other.slope():
            ''' check if the two line are parellel '''
            return True

    def equals(self,other):
        ''' function check if two line are equals '''
        if self.slope()==other.slope() and self.y_intersect()==other.y_intersect():
            ''' check if two line are the same '''
            return True

    def line_intersection(self, other):
        xdiff = (self.__point_1.getX() - self.__point_2.getX(), other.__point_1.getX() - other.__point_2.getX())
        ydiff = (self.__point_1.getY() - self.__point_2.getY(), other.__point_1.getY() - other.__point_2.getY())
        def det(a, b):
            return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]
        div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
        if div == 0:
            raise Exception('lines do not intersect')
        d = (det(*self), det(*other))
        x = det(d, xdiff) / div
        y = det(d, ydiff) / div
        return x, y 


def main():

    p1=Point(-2,0)
    p2=Point(6,4)
    l=Line(p1,p2)

    p11=Point(6,0)
    p22=Point(0,6)
    l1=Line(p11,p22)

    print(l.line_intersection(l1))

main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `*self` to be?

Comment: (point_1 , point_2) and every point have x,y

Comment: in this case  l.line_intersection(l1) , l is the self and l1 is the other

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to illustrate your question.

Comment: `det` takes 2 arguments, each of which is indexable.  Apparently the following `div` line works right.  `self` a `Line` has 2 `point` attribues, which are accessed in the `xdiff` line, but no mechanism to allow * unpacking.  In other words you can't do `self[0]` and `self[1]`.

Comment: And a `Point` object isn't iterable either.  Make sure you understand how `xdiff` expression works, and why it can be used in `det`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use unpacking on `Line` objects you need to define the `__iter__` magic function. Something like:

```
class Line:
    def __iter__(self):
        for p in (self.point1, self.point2):
            yield p
```

On another note, you may want to use [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) for your class definition.

Comment: I use it, I don't know what yield does, I can see its kind of return, and now I have TypeError: 'Point' object is not subscribable

Comment: Yes because your class `Point` cannot be indexed with `[0]` or `[1]`. Maybe you mean `a.getX`?

Comment: i try this, d = (det(self.__point_1,self.__point_2), det(other.__point_1,other.__point_2)) , and give the same error that __iter__ gives me

Comment: already try getx and gety, its shows
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getX'